# Can someone explain why I shouldn't update a value in React `context` directly?

Tags: reactjs

I'm supplying context via a provider to a child component via consumer. Inside of that consumer component, if the user takes an action, I'd like to update a particular value in context, so that all other consumer components have access to the new context value.

I understand that from the React documentation, the right way to do this is to also pass a setter function in context, which will update the value in state on the component that is responsible for creating the context provider itself.

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component

What I'm wondering is why can't I just do something as simple as this:

`this.context.X = Y;`

It seems to work, and I don't see any noticeable side effects, but I'm thinking there must be a reason why the React docs don't show this approach.

Comment: the same reasons as for `setState()` ?

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? And is that just a guess, or is that an answer?

Comment: do you know anything about state, updating, async nature etc? read these docs first

Comment: The short answer is that react won't know you made any change and won't know to re-render